# How can I use resource files in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, build

I am trying to access a file in my src folder.

```
 skillImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/flame.png"));
```

This will produce an exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
```

I've checked that src actually is my source folder (properties -> java build path -> Game/src is listed)

When I'm running it from a jar it works just fine.

Comment: Is `"/flame.png"` instead of `"flame.png"` a typo?

Comment: nope, but it doesn't change the outcome. same exception

Answer (score 1):

Generally, [`getResourceAsStream(String name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) works for JAR files as well as for unpacked class folders. Please note the following:

1. Use **`"flame.png"`** instead of `"/flame.png"` as resource name
2. **Make sure, `flame.png` is copied to the package output folder** (`bin/...`) of the class where `getClass()` is called:

   - Plain Java projects: just copy the file into the package containing the class with the code `getClass().getResourceAsStream("flame.png")`:

[image]

- Maven Java projects: for a class `com.example.Foo` containing the code `getClass()`, the default location for `flame.png` would be `src/main/resources/com/example/`:

[image]